# What kind of questions are we not allowed to ask?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212992/how-to-write-double-summation-series-in-programming):
It kept getting downvotes but I was wondering why, as it's an information-acquiring question about summation inputs.

Comment: Have you read the [help]? Specifically, [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)?

Comment: @Ben , i read it and as far as i read it said 


a specific programming problem
a software algorithm
software tools commonly used by programmers
practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development - which makes me wonder whats wrong with my questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is unclear. You started it off by tagging it [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c). So which one is it? If you were trying to say that you don't care about the specific language (i.e. it doesn't matter for your question) then perhaps use [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic).

Secondly, what is it you're asking? Are you asking whether what you've coded corresponds to the assignment you've been given? That is, if it's a correct implementation?

And third, the comments show that you possibly didn't spend all that much time on this question, hurrying to post it and thereby confusing others:

> oops i wrote that code in here in a rush , sorry about that my mistake doing multiple stuff here atm , i fixed it now

Don't write the code in a rush. Take your time, make sure that what you've written is correct, and use the infinite amount of time you have before posting to check if all is okay. If so, then post it.

Those are 3 reasons I see for downvoting your question. Address them, and you'll have something that's better at least. Depending on the exact question you want to ask, it might even be on-topic. But as Ben commented, read through those resources to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

According to me.

- You should Post what you tried if you try anything.
- Simply try to explain your problem
- If you got any Errors - Please Post the Stack
- Don ask Questions relative to People (ex- What is best color for footer? How to arrage list??)

Thank You.